# Start tomcat service with the help of a batch script in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, cmd

I have created a batch file for launching command prompt with admin rights. What I am trying to achieve here is to run cmd in admin mode using the batch file that I have created and then start tomcat service in that elevated command prompt using java code.

The contents of my bat file are as follows:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
   echo Requesting administrative privileges...     Click yes.
   goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
   echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   set params = %*:"=""
   echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "%params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

   "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   exit /B

:gotAdmin
   if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
   pushd "%CD%"
   CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```

My java code:

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c adminrights.bat  net start Tomcat7 ", null, new File("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.92\\bin"));
BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             String l;
             while((l=BR.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.print(l);
         }
```

Iam not really sure about where to place the net start `Tomcat7` command.

Comment: There is something wrong at the `set params = %*:"=""` line. Use `set "params=%*"` instead (no spaces around the `=`, nothing following `*`). Then you _could_ add the `%*` line  somewhere below the `:gotAdmin` label, I think (use `echo "%*"&pause` until debugged).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script it's working fine it's the Java code that is not working !!

Comment: Not sure where to place the net start command

Answer (score 0):

So you are not sure where to place 'net start tomcat7'?
I would expect from your description the batch file would request admin privileges and then start the service. Thus the command would go somewhere after

```
:gotAdmin
```

The java code might not properly empty the buffers of the subprocess (a requirement on Windows platforms to prevent the process gets stuck). So make sure to not only read from stdout but also stderr.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html